# How to call this web-service? send a XML String with POST or GET to web-service and receive a XML

Tags: xml, web-services

Its quite simpel: How do i call a web-service which can receive a XML-String sent with GET or POST and after processing some stuff, depends on the XML-String, also just returns a XML-String to the client?

It's not SOAP nor REST.

POX? simple HTTP request Web-service?

Edit: Is there a specific name for web-services which only deal with xml receives and responses?

Comment: Do you mean a RESTful Web Service? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services

Comment: I do not use any kind of PUT, POST, GET or Delete or any other Methods from HTTP. U just send a String with POST/GET to a web-service and receive immediately a xml-string response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a web service, and in this case, happens to accept and emit XML. If it also adheres to the ideals of REST, then it is also REST.

There's little value in spending time trying to label or categorize a particular service other than indicating basic things about it. The specification for what it does, what it accepts as input, and what it gives as output is *much* more valuable.

Comment: so there is no specific name for a web service which only deals with XML? receive and response xml.

Comment: Not that I know of, but I don't particularly _care_ what the services I use are classified as. I simply use the services that do what I need. If a service uses XML, I use libraries to deal with XML-based services. The same is true for JSON, SOAP, and services that use their own sort of "serialization". (I often have more work in those cases)